# Ordenar objeto por propiedad en javascript

Tags: javascript, angular

tengo el siguiente objeto

```
let data = [{
"dia": 1,
"Dic 2019": 40000,
"Nov 2019": 100000,
"Oct 2019": 20000 
},{
"dia": 2,
"Dic 2019": 60000,
"Nov 2019": 1000,
"Oct 2019": 200000
}];
```

como podria organizar cada objeto deacuerdo a sus propiedades de mayor a menor para que el resultado fuera

```
let data = [{
    "dia": 1,
     "Nov 2019": 100000,
     "Dic 2019": 40000,
     "Oct 2019": 20000 
    },{
    "dia": 2,
    "Oct 2019": 200000
    "Dic 2019": 60000,
    "Nov 2019": 1000,
    }];
```

estuve revisando algunos ejemplos y encontre la funcion sort que me organiza los objetos, pero en mi caso necesito organizar las propiedades de cada objeto

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te recomiendo que cambies la estructura y pasar de un objeto a un array de objetos para que puedas ordenar, ya que los objetos de javascript en teoria no deberian ser ordenados porque no tienen un indice de propiedad, sino que tienen un nombre

```js
const data = [
    {
        dia: 1,
        meses : [
            {"mes": "Dic 2019", "value": 40000},
            {"mes": "Nov 2019", "value": 100000},
            {"mes": "Oct 2019", "value": 20000 }
        ]
    },
    {
        dia: 2,
        meses : [
            {"mes": "Dic 2019", "value": 60000},
            {"mes": "Nov 2019", "value": 1000},
            {"mes": "Oct 2019", "value": 200000 }
        ]
    }
]

data.map((dia) => {
    dia.meses.sort((a, b) => {
        return a.value > b.value ? -1 : 1
    })
    return console.log(dia)
})
```